# how to fix EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) in swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Am making image library that make me abel to select multiple image from the collection view that i made
When i fun my code averting is good ,but when i press select button this error happen "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

this is the select button code

```
@IBAction func Select(sender: AnyObject) {
    var ckeck = AssetCell() as? AssetCell
    ckeck!.CheckMarkView1.hidden = false // here it shows an error which is "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"
                                         }
```

i had Assetcell class that contain CheckMarkView1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `AssetCell() as? AssetCell` it means that your `ckeck` is an Optional, which again means that it can be something or it can be nil (nothing).

When you in the next line say `ckeck!`, that means that you are telling the compiler to just handle the value of `ckeck` and you don't care whether it is nil or not. This is almost always a bad idea as you have just found out the hard way.

A better way is to use either `if let` syntax to unwrap or `guard` syntax.

So you could say:

```
if let ckeck = ckeck {
    ckeck!.CheckMarkView1.hidden = false
}
```

Or you could say:

```
guard let ckeck = ckeck else { return }
ckeck!.CheckMarkView1.hidden = false
```

That way you are sure to only start using `ckeck` if it actually has a value.

Having said that, the way you actually create `ckeck` looks a bit odd:

```
var ckeck = AssetCell() as? AssetCell
```

Now I don't know the details, but couldn't you just say

```
let ckeck = AssetCell()
```

And finally...this question has been asked a great many times already in various forms. I know that it is frustrating when you have an error and you don't quite understand what is going on, but the next time you should start with a search for `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` for instance. This should return a lot of answers to help you solve the problem, or at least help you get a clue about what is happening. Sorry :)